# Log4net config file not found

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am trying to set the Log4net configuration in a project and I want the configuration to be in a different config file. The thing is, the app.config doesn't read the log4net.config file. 
I added this to my assembly

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

as well as like this

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator( Watch = true)]
```

but it's still not reading the file. 
If I place the log4net configuration inside the app.config file, it runs without a problem. It works great but when I try to specify a config source via app.config like so:

```
<log4net configSource="Web.log4net.config"/>
```

I get an error that the Web.Log4net.config cannot be parsed... 
The app.config and the Web.Log4net.config are in the same project.Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you set `Copy always` for your config file?

Comment: Yup, I did that too.

Comment: _"cannot be parsed"_ - did you check validity? Typos? Anything like that?